# How do I control where my primary and replica shards are located?

Tags: elasticsearch

So I have two `zones`s: `fast` and `slow`.

I'm looking to ensure the primary shards are in the `fast` nodes and the replicas are in the `slow` nodes.

I have the following cluster settings:

```
cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes: zone
cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.force.zone.values: fast,slow
```

If I add the following at index level:

```
"index.routing.allocation.require.zone": "fast"
```

It will allocate ONLY the primaries to `fast`. I could then be cheeky and do the following:

```
"index.routing.allocation.require.zone": "fast,slow"
```

and it would allocate the replicas to `slow`...as desired.

However, if I stop the `fast` nodes, it will allocate all the primary shared to `slow` nodes. When `fast` nodes come back online, they are allocated as replicas.

So the question is. How can I ensure that `fast` nodes are marked as primary when they are online for a given index?

Comment: Write operations happen on primary first and then replicas. Searches, however, can happen on any shard type, whether primary or replica, doesn't make any difference in speed. So can you explain the reason why you want the primary shards to be located on the fast nodes?

Comment: @Val - its to do with the underlying hardware. I want to ensure there are more shards (replicas) on `slow` as the hardware is more reliable. There should be `2` on `slow` for every `1` in `fast`

Comment: Can you define "more reliable"?

Comment: @Val - Backed by a NFS, whereas `fast` either has ephemeral disk or tmpfs

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean primary should be on fast and replicas on slow. If you were to lose a primary, a replica would be automatically promoted to primary, there's literally no difference between them, they are exact copies containing the exact same set of documents.

Comment: @Val - you are absolutely right. Rather embarrassingly I think my question has changed half way through the discussion - perhaps as a result of the information on this page! Not sure what the etiquette is here, so I'll edit the original question.

Comment: You should probably create a new question, maybe referencing this one for the context

Answer (score 0):

while your actions might *temporarily* get what you want, you can't guarantee this will always happen

allocation is done on an index level irrespective of it being a primary or a replica shard

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I phrazed my question incorrectly. Lets say I have `3` instances of a given shard. I'm looking for `2` of those to be in `slow` because the hardware is more reliable.

Comment: if you are using allocation filtering you can assign an index to multiple tags. in this example you'd need 2 nodes with the `slow` tag and 1 with the `fast` tag for this approach to work

Comment: I have 5 x `fast` and 5 x `slow` nodes. Are you saying it is possible? or are you saying its only possible with 1 x `fast` and 2 x `slow` nodes

Comment: yes. otherwise it'd just allocate any of the index shards to any of the 10 nodes you have