# Controlling where shards are allocated

Tags: elasticsearch

My setup:

- two `zones`s: `fast` and `slow` with `5` nodes each.
- `fast` nodes have ephemeral storage, whereas the `slow` nodes are NFS based.
- Running Elasticsearch OSS `v7.7.1`. (I have no control over the version)
- I have the following cluster setting: `cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes: zone`
- My index has 2 replicas, so 3 shard instances (1x primary, 2x replica)

I am trying to ensure the following:

- 1 of the 3 shard instances to be located in zone `fast`.
- 2 of the 3 shard instances to be located in zone `slow` (because it has persistent storage)
- Queries to be run in shard in zone `fast` where available.
- Inserts to only return as written once its written once its been replicated.

Is this setup possible?

Link to a related question: [How do I control where my primary and replica shards are located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72294812/how-do-i-control-where-my-primary-and-replica-shards-are-located?noredirect=1#comment127762563_72294812)

**EDIT to add extra information:**

Both `fast` and `slow` nodes run on a PaaS offering where we are not in control of hardware restarts meaning there can technically be non-graceful shutdowns/restarts at any point.

I'm worried about unflushed data and/or index corruption so I am looking for multiple replicas to be on the `slow` zone nodes backed by NFS to reduce the likelihood of data loss, despite the fact that this will "overload" the `slow` zone with redundant data.

Comment: In the other question you also enabled forced awareness. Is this the case here too? Using forced awareness and only two zones, one set of replicas will stay unassigned.

Comment: Regardless of forced awareness or not, another observation is that if you have the same amount of nodes in the two zones, but twice as many replicas than primaries, one zone is going to look overloaded compared to the other, and that's not good.

Comment: @Val - I figured that by messing around myself, so I removed that config from this question....I do have control over the elastic search cluster settings. I've added an edit to answer the question of why I want to overload the `slow` zone